# How to change element tag without affecting its children?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul id="randomList">
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
</ul>
```

How can I use vanilla JS to select `#randomList` and change the parent element's tags (both beginning and ending tag) so the output is the following:

```
<div id="randomList">
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can change the type of a DOM element.